# R parallel job hangs

Tags: r, slurm, snow

I am running the snow-test.R script as written on the site:

https://hpcf.umbc.edu/other-packages/how-to-run-r-programs-on-maya/

The script is run on a cluster using SLURM with the command:

```
mpirun -np 1 R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore snow-test.R out.dat
```

The R version is 3.5.1. Although the script runs and displays the
result, it hangs at the end. Thus, I need to kill the process
manually from the `SLURM` queue with `scancel` command.

Also, when I change the R version to 3.4.4 using the same scripts,
R cannot run the script, it complains with the message:

```
Error in Rmpi::mpi.comm.spawn(slave = mpitask, slavearg = args, nslaves = count,  : 
  MPI_ERR_SPAWN: could not spawn processes
Calls: makeMPIcluster -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe because you use `-np 1` so only one task, and the script tries to communicate between tasks. Did you try with other `np` values?

Comment: yes, -np with other values didn't work with any version I wrote above

Comment: Did you try with `Rscript --vanilla` instead of  `R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore`? Sometimes `R CMD BATCH` is problematic when multiple processes try to modify the same out file...

Comment: I tried your suggestion, thanks, however, the outcome is the same. R hangs.